# Example for Fourier transform in $C_b^0$

Tags: fourier-analysis

$C_b^0(\mathbb{R})=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}),\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0\}$

So can we construct an function in $C_b^0(\mathbb{R})$ such that it's Fourier transform is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

What kinds of sufficient property does it have?

Comment: I would try something like $|x|e^{-x^2}$ or other related functions. I'm not sure that this will work though. Also, see this mathoverflow thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3764/does-there-exist-a-continuous-function-of-compact-support-with-fourier-transform

Comment: @Moya Not possible because $|x|e^{-x^2}$ is moderate decrease. In fact such example should not be $L^2$.